# Can Ionic 3 App handle 500,000 to 1M users?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am building an App on Ionic 3.
How many users can ionic 3 platform handle?

Is Ionic 3 scalable to 500,000-1,000,000 users?

The App is a basic Progress Tracking Tool and a user is expected to open it 1-2 times per day for max 5 min.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Whether Ionic can handle it isn't the question here, it depends entirely on the foundations on which your app is built.

If your app requires connections to a single or multiple APIs and a full backend system, it will be how well your server can process those loads.

Each instance of an Ionic application will work perfectly fine if built correctly as they're isolated to the device in which it is installed. It's all the important stuff working in the background to serve content to your app which is important.

To provide a primitive example; imagine a social media app like Facebook or Twitter. Let's assume both apps are built to sensible coding standards. If you were to plug either of those apps in to a server that was essentially a dusty old box underneath someone's desk, the entire system would completely crash. There's no way it could handle all of the requests for information because the technology simply can't process it.

The reason they don't crash is because they have large-scale data centres, capable of serving millions if not billions of requests simultaneously - they have good servers.

**Moral of the story**:
If you're building an app, arguably for any size but certainly for 500K+ people, start with your foundations first. The foundation is the servers/data points which will serve your app. Build that correct, and your Ionic app will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.
The app it self is self contained, your backend will be the bottleneck here.